# Consuming REST service with Ajax - Same origin policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I'm writing my first Knockout Js application and I'm stuck trying to make an ajax request to my service (I'm new to web development in general).

I already found out that the problem is same-origin policy, and the reason I'm getting blocked by this I think has to do with my development setup: I'm using WebStorm to write my html/js and launching the page with its built-in webserver, which serves at port 63342; and my REST service is self-hosted, written in go, and running at 8080.

When the application is finished, I'd like to serve both the REST api and the Web app from my go server, but while developing the WebStrom server is really convenient.

Do any of you guys have similar problems? How do you work it out? Should I try to serve everything from my go server even during development? My server is not ready to serve any static content yet. Or should I try to use PJSON, even though I don't think I need it in my final app?

This is the error I get in my chrome develoment tools:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/lines/03/pos. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Do you have the possibility to switch from HTTP 1.1 to 2? HTTP 2 offers [multiplexing which makes domain-sharding redundant](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2916548/java-web-development/http-2-for-java-developers.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could CORS-enable your REST service, and make sure that your web app is sending CORS request headers.

I'm not proficient in either Go or WebStorm, but I recommend investigating CORS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it took only a couple of lines of code to serve static content from my go server, so I just did that and now everything is working fine.

Thanks for your help though!

Best regards